# Facebook send message puts in wrong URL

Tags: sendmessage, facebook-social-plugins, fb.ui

We are trying to use either the facebook send social plugin, or the fb.ui send dialog. In both cases, we have found the link or href we pass to facebook only mostly works. There are 3 places a link is placed in the message and they are:

1. The title of the message
2. A link right below the title
3. an image to the left of the description

1 and 3 seem to respect the link parameter, but 2 is not. Here is an example of the code we are using:

```
FB.ui({
      method: 'send',
      name: 'Referral',
      link: 'https://www.oursite.com/?refer=123',
      picture: 'http://www.oursite.com/assets/images/logo.png',
      name:'heres a name',
      description:'description'
      });
```

When this gets sent the link https://www.oursite.com/?refer=123 works for the name and the picture, but not the link output right below the name. Here is the code we're using for the social plugin which yields the same effect:

```
<div class="fb-send" data-href="https://www.oursite.com/?refer=123"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Facebook doesn't use your link parameter: it uses the og:url meta of the page you want to share.
If you use the fb-send plugin, you can have a look to the data-ref attribute : it should do the job :)

You should also have a look here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to know what URL Facebook will use at the end.

Good luck